# Relation between the eigenvalues of symmetric $A$, $B$ and $A+B$ when $AB=(BA)^{T}$

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two real symmetric matrices. If $AB=(BA)^{T}$ then, is there any relation between the eigenvalues of $A+B$ and eigenvalues of $A$, $ B$?

If $A$ and $B$ be two real symmetric matrices such that $AB=BA$, then the eigenvalues of $A+B$ is the sum of eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ in some order. The similar way, can we express the eigenvalues $A+B$ using the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ when $AB$=transpose of $BA$.

Comment: The conditions that $A,B$ commute and $AB=(AB)^T$ that you mention in the second paragraph are actually _the same_ condition (for symmetric $A,B$), so you are saying the same thing twice. However the condition $AB=(BA)^T$ of your title is no condition at all  (for symmetric $A,B$), as the answer notes.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ must have a common eigenvector for you to conclude that some eigenvalue of $A+B$ is the sum of a pair eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that for *any* two symmetric matrices $A, B$, we have
$$
(BA)^T = A^TB^T = AB
$$
so assuming that $(BA)^T=AB$ doesn't actually let us conclude anything that we couldn't already conclude from $A$ and $B$ being symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

If A and B has same eigenvector, then $Ae=\lambda e$ and $Be=\mu e$ $\implies$ $(A+B)e=(\lambda+\mu)e$.

If there is no relationship between eigenvectors, then there cannot be any relationship between the eigenvalues. However, if B is a perturbation of A, then the eigenvectors might be similar, in which case the above statement holds approximately.

Also, see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4224/eigenvalues-of-matrix-sums).